Can global namespace solution in react-navigation be used independently?
In the typescript-section of react navigation it is mentioned, that we can either annotate all the navigation props in all the screens or if we use a lot of useNavigation() and links we can declare a global namespace and extend the root navigator. My question is can we just use the declare global {} syntax and will it correctly suggest the functions for that navigation, wherever we use the useNavigation hook. My code looks like as given below.
export type RootStackNavigatorParamsList = {
  NavigatorC: NavigatorScreenParams<StackNavigatorC>;
  NavigatorB: NavigatorScreenParams<StackNavigatorB>;
  NavigatorA: NavigatorScreenParams<StackNavigatorA>;
  DrawerNavigator: NavigatorScreenParams<DrawerNavigatorParamList>;
};

export type DrawerNavigatorParamList = {
  TabNavigator: NavigatorScreenParams<TabNavigatorParamList>;
};

export type TabNavigatorParamList = {
  NavigatorD: NavigatorScreenParams<StackNavigatorD>;
  NavigatorE: NavigatorScreenParams<StackNavigatorE>;
  NavigatorF: NavigatorScreenParams<StackNavigatorF>;
};

declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackNavigatorParamsList {}
  }
}

Now inside ScreenF in NavigatorF when I call navigation.toggleDrawer(). It gives me the type error that :

Property 'toggleDrawer' does not exist on type
'Omit<NavigationProp, "getState"> & { getState():
Readonly<{ key: string; index: number; routeNames: string[]; history?:
unknown[] | undefined; routes: NavigationRoute<...>[]; type: string;
stale: false; }> | undefined; }'.

Here navigation = useNavigation()
But when I explicitly define the type for this screen and use it then its fine
type ScreenFProps<T extends keyof StackNavigatorF> = CompositeScreenProps<
  CompositeScreenProps<
    CompositeScreenProps<
      StackScreenProps<StackNavigatorF, T>,
      BottomTabScreenProps<TabNavigatorParamList>
    >,
    DrawerScreenProps<DrawerNavigatorParamList>
  >,
  StackScreenProps<RootStackNavigatorParamsList>
>;

navigation =
    useNavigation<HomeScreenProps<"HomeScreen">["navigation"]>();

Will redeclaring the global namespace not start suggesting the methods correctly, as is implied in the docs or am I doing something wrong?
